# How to make progression bar to change color after reaching 100%?

Tags: javascript

I have some problem about JavaScript and using if in it. I have some experiences in PHP, but this is another world for me. I need to do something like this: I have "progress bar" with two buttons (+ and -), when I press button the value in function will change +- 0.1 which move the bar and change %.

I want to change to color of the progress bar when it's more then 100%. I tried to make another fill called filler with 0 rotate. When x is 1 or more then rotate depends on value2 = y + 0.1 per click. It works, but with 2 + buttons and I want it to only with one. If(x>1) doesn't work with `document.write`.

**images:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t32z.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woybe.png]

**demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/dmytxja2

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

const gaugeElement = document.querySelector(".gauge");

function setGaugeValue(gauge, value) {
  if (value < 0 || value > 3) {
    return;
  }

  gauge.querySelector(".gauge__fill").style.transform = `rotate(${value / 2}turn)`;
  gauge.querySelector(".gauge__filler").style.transform = `rotate(${0}turn)`;

  value2 = y;
  gauge.querySelector(".gauge__filler").style.transform = `rotate(${value2 / 2}turn)`;


  gauge.querySelector(".gauge__cover").textContent = `${Math.round(value * 100)}%`;
}

setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, x);

if (x >= 1) {
  var cc = document.getElementById('outer');
  cc.style.visibility = "visible";
}

document.write('<button id="iner" onclick="setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, x = x + 0.1)">+</button>');
document.write('<button id="outer" hidden="hidden" onclick="setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, y = y + 0.1)">+</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, x = x - 0.1)">-</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="alert(x);">test</button>');
```

```css
.gauge {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #004033;
}

.gauge__body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background: #b4c0be;
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 100% 200%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100% 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gauge__fill {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotate(0.25turn);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}

.gauge__filler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotate(0.25turn);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}

.gauge__cover {
  width: 75%;
  height: 150%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /* Text */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="gauge">
  <div class="gauge__body">
    <div class="gauge__fill"></div>
    <div class="gauge__filler"></div>
    <div class="gauge__cover"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.write`? in 2021?

Comment: You have two image references in your post, but you have not shown them. You may wish to edit your post to insert them `![Alt text][1]` will do it.

Comment: It's beta, I will edit it, but I need firstly function that will work

Comment: Can you at least provider a working example which we can run here or on jsFiddle or somehwere else?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dmytxja2/

Comment: `y` is always 0, so `value2` is always 0. Try instead: `value2 = max(value-1, 0)`

Comment: it's prototype combinated with many tries, I need something which will work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must enter the condition inside the function to be checked each time the function is called

In your code, the condition is only checked for the first time, and because the result is `false`, it does not change

You have also assigned the `hidden` parameter to the button with the `outer` id

But when displaying `outer` you use `style.visibility` which has no effect

**Your modified code:**

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

const gaugeElement = document.querySelector(".gauge");

function setGaugeValue(gauge, value) {
  if (value < 0 || value > 3) {
    return;
  }

  gauge.querySelector(".gauge__fill").style.transform = `rotate(${value / 2}turn)`;
  gauge.querySelector(".gauge__filler").style.transform = `rotate(${0}turn)`;

  value2 = y;
  gauge.querySelector(".gauge__filler").style.transform = `rotate(${value2 / 2}turn)`;


  gauge.querySelector(".gauge__cover").textContent = `${Math.round(value * 100)}%`;
  if (x >= 1) {
    var cc = document.getElementById('outer');
    cc.style.display = "inline";
  }
}

setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, x);



document.write('<button id="iner" onclick="setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, x = x + 0.1)">+</button>');
document.write('<button id="outer" style="display:none;" onclick="setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, y = y + 0.1)">+</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, x = x - 0.1)">-</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="alert(x);">test</button>');
```

```css
.gauge {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #004033;
}

.gauge__body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background: #b4c0be;
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 100% 200%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100% 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gauge__fill {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotate(0.25turn);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}

.gauge__filler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotate(0.25turn);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}

.gauge__cover {
  width: 75%;
  height: 150%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /* Text */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="gauge">
  <div class="gauge__body">
    <div class="gauge__fill"></div>
    <div class="gauge__filler"></div>
    <div class="gauge__cover"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## BUT:

**This code is very, very bad**

As far as I realized

You wanted to make something like this

**My Code :**

```js
var x = 0;
var deg = 0;
const gaugeElement = document.querySelector(".gauge");
const gauge__fill = gaugeElement.querySelector(".gauge__fill");
const gauge__cover = document.querySelector(".gauge__cover");

function setGaugeValue(btn) {
  if (x >= 0) {
    if (gauge__fill.style.transform == "rotate(180deg)" && btn == 'plus') {
      deg = 0;
    }
    if (gauge__fill.style.transform == "rotate(18deg)" && btn == 'minus' && x != 0) {
      deg = 180;
    } else {
      if (btn == 'plus') {
        deg += 18;
      } else {
        deg -= 18;
      }
    }
    gauge__fill.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';

    gauge__cover.textContent = `${x * 10}%`;

    if (x >= 11) {
      gauge__fill.style.background = "green";
    } else {
      gauge__fill.style.background = "red";
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function() {
  x += 1;
  setGaugeValue('plus');
});

document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (x > 0) {
    x -= 1;
    setGaugeValue('minus');
  }
});

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(x);
});
```

```css
.gauge {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #004033;
}

.gauge__body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background: #b4c0be;
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 100% 200%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100% 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gauge__fill {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: center top;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}

.gauge__cover {
  width: 75%;
  height: 150%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /* Text */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="real.css">
  <title>Nutriadapt</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gauge">
    <div class="gauge__body">
      <div class="gauge__fill"></div>
      <div class="gauge__cover">0%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="plus">+</button>
  <button id="minus">-</button>
  <button id="test">test</button>
</body>

</html>
```